# iPhone simulator continues to fail loading a webpage with the error sigabrt

Tags: iphone, browser, sigabrt

I'm building a web browser from scratch and most everything works except for the most important thing. The browser will fail with the error sigabrt and, while I'm new to iPhone programming, I'm pretty sure this means that I'm not sending the URL correctly.

This is the code for loading the webpage by pressing a button.

```
- (IBAction)getURLButton:(NSString *)aString {
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:aString];
NSURLRequest *URLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
BOOL load = [addressBar webView: (goButton) shouldStartLoadWithRequest:URLRequest navigationType:UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted];
if (load) {
    error = nil;
    [goButton loadRequest:URLRequest];
    //currentURLString = [UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.location.href"];
    //It's not in Xcode? It continues to get an error after I write the above statement.
} else {
    NSString *message = NSURLErrorFailingURLErrorKey;
    NSLog(@"%@",message);
}
```

}

And this is the error message:

```
2013-02-14 16:49:28.724 WebBrowser[1265:c07] -[ViewController getURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x716f1d0
2013-02-14 16:49:28.727 WebBrowser[1265:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController getURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x716f1d0'
```

I know the errors there somewhere, I just don't know where. Help?

Answer (score -1):

```
 2013-02-14 16:49:28.724 WebBrowser[1265:c07] -[ViewController getURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x716f1d0
 2013-02-14 16:49:28.727 WebBrowser[1265:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController getURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x716f1d0'
```

If you see your exception you are calling **getURL:** where as your method name is **getURLButton:**.